# Conflict between ULon and siunitx

Tags: siunitx, ulem

I am trying to create an automatic numbering of remarks which will be highlighted. It does produce the expected result but it crashes and I don't understand what is wrong. Below is the minimum working example.

```
\documentclass[review,5p,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcounter{HLcounter}
\show\ULon
\newcommand{\hl}[1]{\stepcounter{HLcounter}%
    \bgroup\markoverwith{\textcolor{yellow}{\rule[-.5ex]{2pt}{2.5ex}}}%
    \ULon{\,R\arabic{HLcounter}: {#1}\,}}
\begin{document}
efe \hl{testing} test \hl{\SI{60}{\minute}} bla bla
\end{document}
```

Thanks,

Rufus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The break-down-the-input approached used by `ulem` clashes with the hoops `siunitx` jumps through. The best fix is to add an `\mbox`, either to `\hl`:

```
\documentclass[review,5p,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcounter{HLcounter}
\show\ULon
\newcommand{\hl}[1]{\stepcounter{HLcounter}%
    \bgroup\markoverwith{\textcolor{yellow}{\rule[-.5ex]{2pt}{2.5ex}}}%
    \ULon{\,R\arabic{HLcounter}: {\mbox{#1}}\,}}
\begin{document}
efe \hl{testing} test \hl{\SI{60}{\minute}} bla bla
\end{document}
```

or at each use of `\SI` inside `\hl` if you want to do it manually.

Comment: If I use the solution provided in the code (`\mbox` around `#1`) there are no line breaks any more. If I renew the `\SI` `\si` commands, it does work fine.
`\let\siold\si
    \let\SIold\SI
    \renewcommand{\si}[1]{\mbox{\siold{#1}}}
    \renewcommand{\SI}[2]{\mbox{\SIold{#1}{#2}}}`